# How to instantiate a StructDescriptor object of a type that is inside in a package

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

I have a package in oracle 12 that declares his own types for be processed by differents stored procedures, the hierarchy is:

[image]

i'm trying to call a stored procedure that uses this types as IN parameters but when i try to execute this java code:

```
StructDescriptor sd = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("PKG_ACEPTACION_SOLICITUD.tb_basicos", conexion);
ArrayDescriptor ad = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("PKG_ACEPTACION_SOLICITUD.rg_basicos", conexion);
```

...the exception is:

```
Unable to resolve type "PKG_ACEPTACION_SOLICITUD.tb_basicos"
```

But, when i create the java objects from the types declared public, outside of the package the proccess run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **it's not possible to use PL/SQL types in Java** (those declared in your package). As a workaround, you should create **SQL type instead**:

```
create type your_type is object (
    prop1 varchar2(10),
    prop2 varchar2(10)
)
```

And return it from your PL/SQL package.

Then, in Java, you can use `OracleCallableStatement` as follows:

```
OracleCallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement)connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call your_package.your_function}"); ;
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.JAVA_STRUCT, "YOUR_TYPE");
```